# Getting data of a direct buffer object returned from JNI method to Java?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI and struggling to implement one requirement.  I have
allocated direct buffer in JNI using `NewDirectByteBuffer()` API and
want to access the buffer on Java side.

What I did is I have allocated a native memory and stored some data in that buffer.Then I wrapped that memory space in a direct buffer object using `NewDirectByteBuffer()` API.

Then to read the data at that memory from JAVA, I returned that direct buffer object(`BufferObject`) to java side and read using `BufferObject.get()` method.

But cannot managed to get the data i stored in the direct buffer.Please let me is that way correct to read data of a direct buffer object which was created using `NewDirectByteBuffer()`?

Comment: "Cannot manage to get the data" is not an adequate problem specification. Try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I always do which has worked (which doesn't mean its the best way) is

- create the direct ByteBuffer in Java.
- pass it to a JNI method to populate (updating the data and setting the position and limit correctly)
- use `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())` so the data will be read/written in native byte ordering.
- re-use the ByteBuffer as much as possible as its relatively expensive to create and free.

i.e. I do as little in native code as possible. ;)

> But cannot managed to get the data i stored in the direct buffer.

Unfortunately, that could mean just about anything.

Part of the reason for doing as much in Java as possible is it simplifies debugging.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your answer.

I think..the way you do is better when I have few things to do in JNI method. In my case, I need to process the data in native code first and then pass it to java to use in some function. I need to do further processing of those data at JNI side later on. So, there are some other substantial job need to be done in native code. 



Is there any other way to access the data from Direct buffer object created in JNI method ? 

thanks in advance. :)

Comment: AFAIK, The only other way, is the way you are doing it now.  You populate the data of a ByteBuffer you created in JNI, return the ByteBuffer, and read it in Java code.  You have to make sure your position and limit are correct before reading the data.

Comment: I have solved the problem. That's a silly error with index/position. Thank you for ur suggestions. :)

Comment: @Alisha You can accept this answer by ticking on the left hand side of the question. ;)

Comment: @Alisha can you past the code how did you solve, as I have the same problem.